# Extract a sequence of digits from database

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

Is there a way to select a sequence of digits ( I am thinking of something like regex) from database?

In example: I have a following set of integers:

> 487119241 487130101 486614011 481124234 484031341 487110 48712

and I would like to extract only these which fit into the pattern 4871;
I know that in Python I could do re.match('4871[0-9]+', mySet) but I don't know of any mechanism like that in mySQL.

I was thinking maybe of something `SELECT integers FROM db WHERE myNumber > SOME_VALUE;` but this won't work as the pattern may vary from 5 to 7 digits.

Comment: You can use regex in SQL queries in MySQL. You can read more about that in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: Are those integers stored one-per-row, not all in one string?  If so, @jaunbits needs to anchor his suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field REGEXP '4871[0-9]+'
```

Comment: It's not explicit in the question but, given the suggestion about using mynumber > somevalue and the example data, this probably needs to be anchored with ^ at the start of the regex otherwise you'll match anywhere in the number.